# Autocomplete in TeXworks

Tags: texworks

Some command should be preceded by slash to auto-complete works (e.g. `rule`) and some command works without preceding slash (e.g. `parbox`). Is there any rule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is any particular rule that has been applied. The command completion rules for TeXworks were inherited from those created by Herb Schulz for TeXShop, and they were based largely on his personal set originally, if I recall.

You can inspect the full list of autocompletions by opening the `tw-latex.txt` file inside the `<resources>/completion` folder.  (Depending on your OS, this folder will be in different locations; you can find it by choosing the Settings and Resources menu item in the Help menu.)