# How to add new auto-complete options in TeXworks?

Tags: editors, texworks, auto-completion

I'm working with TeXworks. It has some auto completions but not enough. How can I add some auto completion to it. Is there any way to add them from TeXmaker to TeXworks.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118038/texworks-auto-complete See also https://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/CodeCompletion I don't have time at the moment, but I (or anyone else who wants to) can write a better answer later.

Comment: I read (tex.stack ... auto-complete). Then I went to D:\programs\texlive\texmf-config\texworks\completion and change the tw-latex.txt. I insert some codes for "bb" similar to "bf" everywhere then save and close it. But It doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly did you insert? Was TeXworks open at the time? If so you need to restart it.

Comment: mbb:=\mathbb{#INS#} before mbf:=\mathbf{#INS#}     and     
\mathbb{#INS#}\mbb:=\mathbb{#INS#} before \mathbf{#INS#}\mbf:=\mathbf{#INS#}

Comment: Hm, worked fine here, in Kubuntu. If you in TeXworks choose Scripts --> Scripting TeXworks --> Show Scripts Folder, do you get the folder `D:\programs\texlive\texmf-config\texworks\scripts`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11510/discussion-between-hoseyn-heydari-and-torbjorn-t)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I collocated these in my discussion with [Torbjørn T](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbjorn-t) and this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118038/texworks-auto-complete) to find my way:

1. You should open your TeXworks, choose Scripts--> Scripting TeXworks --> Show Scripts Folder.
2. Then you will achieve folder like "`C:\Users\user\TeXworks\scripts`". You should go to Folder "`C:\Users\user\TeXworks\completion`" instead.
3. TeXworks stores the completion data in a series of files called "`tw-<name>.txt`" here. You can edit related file i.e. add your completion with Notepad or create a new one for your self.(The format of work and some more is detailed  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118038/texworks-auto-complete).)
4. Then save and close it, restart your TeXworks and enjoy new completions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a build folder can be avoided by changing the Bib(la)tex option from bibtex % to bibtex build/%. This should also be done with all other output files in the fields dvisp, Dvipdfm etc. 
This worked for me at least.